# Is it possible to save an currently selected row to a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

In the `DataGridView` if you just have edited an field, you have to deselect or change the currently selected row in order for the changes to be applied in the database.
I was wondering if there is way to deselect the current row so I can update the changes in the database without clicking away from the current row?
Iam using an `DataGridViewButtonColumn` which opens another form, in which I edit the values, but when I try to update the changes to database it wont update(I have already binded these values to `TextBox`), because the row is currently being selected. But if I click another row in `DataGridView` and save, then the changes are applied.
I have already tried commands `dgv.ClearSelection();` and `dgv.CurrentCell = null;`

Comment: Try calling the grid's `EndEdit()` method.

Comment: Didnt work, because I dont specifically edit the field, but use `BindingSource` to use selected rows fields in another form, but when I try to save from it, it wont update to db.(Yes it worked if I edit the field manually, but if I edit it programmatically it wont update)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates/reproduces your claim.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.